# How do I skip blank cells using MailApp.SendEmail?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I've been using Google form to collect information to a workbook, then using that information to send customized emails back to the sender. I am a noob at coding, but I have managed to cobble together enough for this task.  My problem is that, when it comes to a blank email cell it stops.  I've tried to put in a loop to make it skip, with no success.  Any help would be appreciated.  This is the program I am using without a loop.

```
// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2000;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B2001
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2001)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var emailSent = row[2];     // Third column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Bounce Reply";  
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string.match() function to determine if a cell is empty or not. Since you are looking for email address you might as well see if the cell has '@' sign. If not exclude the cell and continue on to the next cell like so:

```
if (emailAddress.match('@')  === null){
 continue;  // skip this iteration of the loop and go to the next one
}
```

Your final code will look like:

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2000;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B2001
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2001)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]  // First column
    if (emailAddress.match('@')  === null){
       continue;  // skip this iteration of the loop and go to the next one
    };  
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var emailSent = row[2];     // Third column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Bounce Reply";  
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
    }
  }
```

**Edit**

To check if something is empty or not you can try something like this.

```
if (message.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9_]/) === null) {  //" /[a-zA-Z0-9_]/ " is regex  to match any and every alphanumeric letter including underscore
 continue; // skip this iteration of the loop and go to the next one
}
```

You can find more details on function [match and regex here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks!  That was exactly what I needed.  It seems like such and obvious fix after you point it out.

Comment: Thanks!  That was exactly what I needed.  It seems like such and obvious fix after you point it out.  Is there a way to use this to make it skip if the email is blank or the message is blank?  Like  using  '|| message.match () ===null'.  I know it won't let me match an undefined condition, so how would I do that?

Comment: Undefined condition? What do you mean by that?

Comment: When you use .match () you have to define what you are matching (or at least that is my understanding).  It won't let you leave the () empty, and I don't have something that would be guaranteed to be in there like the @ for the email address.

Comment: I have updated the answer to check for empty message body and also provided links which provide more details on match and regex. Hope that will clarify things!

Comment: Much appreciated!  Thank you again for your help.